# Вывод с бд с двух таблиц в json

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, json

Есть 2 таблицы

dle_ingredients_cat

```
(1, 'fructi', 'Фрукты и ягоды'),
(2, 'ovoshi', 'Овощи'),
(3, 'zelen', 'Зелень и цветы'),
```

dle_ingredients

```
(1, 'Апельсин', 'fructi', 'Фрукты и ягоды', '190', '', '', '', '36', '0.9', '0.2', '8.1', 'apelsin.jpg'),
(2, 'Ежевика', 'fructi', 'Фрукты и ягоды', '10', '', '', '160', '34', '1.5', '0.5', '4.4', 'ezhevika.jpg'),
(4, 'Батат', 'ovoshi', 'Овощи', '170', '', '', '', '60', '2', '0', '13.8', 'batat.jpg'),
(5, 'Огурец', 'ovoshi', 'Овощи', '120', '', '', '', '14', '0.8', '0.1', '2.5', 'ogurec.jpg'),
(6, 'Петрушка', 'zelen', 'Зелень и цветы', '20', '', '', '', '49', '3.7', '0.4', '7.6', 'petrushka.jpg'),
(7, 'Салат', 'zelen', 'Зелень и цветы', '250', '', '', '', '16', '1.5', '0.2', '2', 'salat.jpg'),
```

Как с них вывести данные в таком json?

```
{
    "fructi": [
        {
            "name": "Апельсин",
            "cat": "Фрукты и ягоды",
            "image": "apelsin.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ежевика",
            "cat": "Фрукты и ягоды",
            "image": "ezhevika.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "ovoshi": [
        {
            "name": "Батат",
            "cat": "Овощи",
            "image": "batat.jpg"
        },
         {
            "name": "Огурец",
            "cat": "Овощи",
            "image": "ogurec.jpg"
         }
    ],
    "zelen": [
        {
            "name": "Петрушка",
            "cat": "Зелень и цветы",
            "image": "petrushka.jpg"
        },
        {
            "name": "Салат",
            "cat": "Зелень и цветы",
            "image": "salat.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе не нужна первая таблица все данные есть во второй, просто достань данные из первой:

```
SELECT * FROM dle_ingredients;
```

Получите примерно массив как $selectArray, и соберите json в php:

```
$selectArray = array(
    "(1, 'Апельсин', 'fructi', 'Фрукты и ягоды', '190', '', '', '', '36', '0.9', '0.2', '8.1', 'apelsin.jpg')",
    "(2, 'Ежевика', 'fructi', 'Фрукты и ягоды', '10', '', '', '160', '34', '1.5', '0.5', '4.4', 'ezhevika.jpg')",
    "(4, 'Батат', 'ovoshi', 'Овощи', '170', '', '', '', '60', '2', '0', '13.8', 'batat.jpg')",
    "(5, 'Огурец', 'ovoshi', 'Овощи', '120', '', '', '', '14', '0.8', '0.1', '2.5', 'ogurec.jpg')",
    "(6, 'Петрушка', 'zelen', 'Зелень и цветы', '20', '', '', '', '49', '3.7', '0.4', '7.6', 'petrushka.jpg')",
    "(7, 'Салат', 'zelen', 'Зелень и цветы', '250', '', '', '', '16', '1.5', '0.2', '2', 'salat.jpg')",
);

$result = array();

foreach ($selectArray as $select) {
    $select = explode(",", preg_replace('/[\(\)]/ui', '', $select));

    $result[$select[2]][] = array(
        'name' => $select[1],
        'cat' => $select[3],
        'image' => $select[12],
    );
}

var_dump(json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```